# Не отображается detailTextLabel в UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios

Подскажите! Не отображается никаким образом эта надпись, какое бы константное значение туда не вписывай.

Comment: А где Вы их записываете? В каком методе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавайте свои ячейки используя стиль `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`

Comment: Или UITableViewCellStyleValue1/2